# Обязательно ли создавать таблицы в бд для выпадающего списка на фронте, или это лучше сделать на бэке?

Tags: база-данных, архитектура, backend

Я БД разработчик Postgres. У меня проблема с Back-end разработчиком, не можем решить проблему со списком значений для выпадающего списка на фронте. Эти выпадающие списки служат только для того, чтобы фильтровать значения из БД.

Он говорит, что нужно создать таблицы для каждого выпадающего списка в БД.
А я говорю, что он может сделать это у себя на бэке (пишет на java spring), с помощью конфигурационных файлов, или еще как нибудь. Потому что со стороны БД и так схема уже большая, и все сущности между собой связаны. А эти таблицы были бы как мусорные, заполняли бы пространство, и не имели бы никакой связи с текущей схемой.

Фильтрация на фронте происходит вот так:
[image: Фильтрация на фронте]

Но в БД передаются только значения True или False. И таблица просто содержала бы описания полей для списка и boolean значение для обоих.

И таких таблиц несколько.

Подскажите, кто прав?

Comment: Эм.. Ну в принципе оба... Но делать на бэке без базы я вообще смысла не вижу - тогда уж на фронте или в базе.

Comment: На этот вопрос невозможно ответить как-то объективно, фильтровать данные можно как и на бд, так и на бэке, так и на фронте, вопрос в том, будет ли использоваться данная фильтрация где либо еще и каков её контекст. Скажем, есть ли какой-то еще модуль который будет использовать тот же комбобокс с теми же значениями?

Comment: @Acinit, Эти фильтры будут только в одном модуле, и причем только на одной странице и для одной формы. И значений всегда только 2, название + True/False

Comment: как сказал @Qwertiy, можно сделать и на бэке и на бд, имхо, но я бы еще подумал над общей реализацией фильтров в принципе во всех проектах вашей базы проектов, в одном случае у нас будет очень много конфигурационных файлов, в другом поле мусорных таблиц, было бы неплохо организовать всё это таким образом, чтобы оно работало как нечто такое единое, к которому можно обращаться и он формирует необходимые фильтры.

Comment: а еще можно ПрЕдПоЛоЖиТь, что ваш заказчик такой типа "ну вооот, мы кароче добавили промежуточный этап межу исполнили и не имполнили, поэтому надо добавить вот этттоооо карочеее"

Comment: Извиняюсь за паразиты в предложениях, сложно описывать вещи из реальной жизни разработки как-то иначе

Comment: Данные должны храниться в БД. Список фильтров (текст и соотв. значение) - это данные. Посему место хранения определяется самой их сутью - в БД. И соответственно на старте приложения они вычитываются, и их копия (достаточно компактная) хранится в клиенте. *эти таблицы были бы как мусорные, заполняли бы пространство, и не имели бы никакой связи с текущей схемой* Одиноко стоящая таблица схемы не усложнит. А вот порядку в системе будет явно больше.

Comment: Тут ответ кроется в реализации бизнес логики, если параметры заводятся в некой админке, то да, хранить нужно в БД, т.е. они имеют состояние и могут возможно в дальнейшем быть как-то инваилированы, тут все логично, однако, если в действительности это просто флаги, то на backend-е в таком случае пишется api и предоставляется к нему документация (список возможных значений) и этого будет достаточно для реализации, если backend хочет, то он может создать как вы сказали некий cfg файл или же enum и отдавать его. Т.е. ответ на ваш вопрос: если не требуется хранить состояние, то хранилище это оверхед.